# static variable persistence in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, static, application-pool

I have used static variable which I hope it will persist in IIS. But for sometimes, it is cleared. Is that possible that IIS will clear the static variable?

```
public partial class Main : CustomPage
 {
    public static bool cachedCurrentYearDataInFile = false;
```

Comment: If the app pool recycles or you switch to a different worker process, then yes.

Comment: Extending @pinkfloydx33 comment, a new worker process could be started if the impersonation is set, different users would start different processes under different user accounts.

Comment: First time in a long time that I see a `iis` tag, and it is relevant

Comment: To avoid different worker process missbehaviour you could use [HttpContext.Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.application(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Answer (score 4):

`static` variables live though the application cycle. If the application ends (chech application pool settings like idle and recycle) a new instance is generated and you would lose all static information of the now non-existant one. If you want persistence you should consider, actual persistence like file/database.